# How to show Data Output in pgAdmin4?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I am querying my postgresql using pgAdmin4.
But query Data Output is not showing.

Only showing message. (like under image).

How to change if showing my query Data Output?

[image]

---

Step by Step.

1. I am querying any query. And show results.
   [image]
2. Chane query and run.
   [image]
3. Click Data ouput tab and showing previous result data. It is not change.
   [image]
4. So I click History tab and showing Rows Affected is -1. But query is valid.
   [image]

Comment: run count(*) instead of * in query with `='A'`

Comment: @VaoTsun I change my query. But same result.

Comment: if it does not show the number of exception - write to pgadmin dev/support team

Comment: what happens If you run the same query from psql?

Comment: @VaoTsun Thanks. :)

Comment: @n33ma Result is same. I found when it is happened. I will send pgadmin dev/support team.

Comment: I posted this bug in postgresql redmine. (https://redmine.postgresql.org)